# Failed to generate pb file when using proto3 version.[Nodejs]

Tags: grpc

1.I yarn add grpc-tools.

2.cmd command: protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./ --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./grpc_node_plugin.exe --grpc_out=./ UHDInterface.proto

3.Finally reported an error

UHDInterface.proto: is a proto3 file that contains optional fields, but code generator protoc-gen-grpc hasn't been updated to support optional fields in proto3. Please ask the owner of this code generator to support proto3 optional.--grpc_out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Protobuf

proto3 **fully** supports `optional` as of [protobuf `3.15.0`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0) ([experimental support was added in v3.12.0 but required passing in a `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` flag to `protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.12.0)).

I also find it weird that it's not documented in the [Language Guide (proto3)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) yet, but you can find some great documentation and examples here - [Protobuf Field Presence](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/field_presence.md).

#### gRPC

To generate gRPC files from proto files using the `optional` keyword, make sure you're using the latest plugins. For JavaScript, you can use the executable included in the `grpc-tools` NPM package - `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc_js=./node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin`.

Alternatively, for other langauges (e.g. Python's `grpcio-tools` unfortunately doesn't include the `grpc_python_plugin` executable, but includes this functionality in `python -m grpc_tools.protoc`), you can try [building the gRPC repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#clone-the-repository-including-submodules) to get the binaries.

Please let me known if anything is unclear and I can edit!

Answer (score 0):

proto3 doesn't support `optional` and `required` filed in message defination any more, just remove these field in `UHDInterface.proto`

You can reference [why messge type remove 'required,optional'?](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2497) for more detail.

Comment: My colleague said that `optional` is added in the latest version. So, I want to ask if this is true? Or where can I see the latest version of the information? Thank you

Comment: Just trust offical document in [Language Guide (proto3)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3)

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague was right, you can use `optional` with protobuf since v3.15.0 as Ayush has previously linked.

Your particular issue is because you need to update `io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java` in your dependency tree.

I'm using v3.15.0 with Maven and had to update my `io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java` like below:

```
<pluginArtifact>
  io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
</pluginArtifact>
```

where `${grpc.version}` = `1.31.0`. See more in [their repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master)

Comment: yes,my colleague is right.https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1717